# Is it true that if $P(x)$ is a square number for every integers, then $P(x)=(Q(x))^2$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients and $deg(P(x))>0$. Is it true that if $P(x)$ is a square number for every integers, then $P(X)=(Q(x))^2$, with $Q(x)$ being a polynomial? Is the statement correct if $P(x)$ is a square number for infinite integers, not every integers ?

Comment: $P(x) = x$ is a perfect square for infnitely many integer inputs, but it is not the square of any other polynomial. So the answer to your second question is no.

Comment: You don't need the condition $\deg(P(x))>0$. If $P(x)=a^2$ is constant, then you can take $Q(x)=a$.

Comment: An even [stronger](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853690/) statement.

Comment: Special case of a well-known result of Davenport, Lewis and Schinzel cited in [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1157825/242)